# scrapy HTML Response content isn't text

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, http, scrapy

This is my code that scans a user and outputs their SteamID and the value of their inventory:

```
import scrapy
import logging

bot_words = [
"bot",
"BOT",
"Bot",
"[tf2mart]"
]

class AccountSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "accounts"
    start_urls = [
        'file:///Users/max/Documents/promotebot/tutorial/tutorial/TF2ITEMS.htm'
    ]

    def linkgen(self):
        global steamid
        print("Downloading Page...")
        yield scrapy.Request("http://www.backpack.tf" + steamid, callback=self.parse_accounts)
        print("Page successfully downloaded.")

    def parse(self, response):
        global steamid
        lgen = self.linkgen()
        for tr in response.css("tbody"):
            for user in response.css("span a"):
                if bot_words not in response.css("span a"):
                    print("Parsed info")
                    print("User: " + user.extract())
                    steamid = user.css('::attr(href)').extract()[0]
                    print("Steam ID: " + steamid)
                    yield lgen.next()

    def parse_accounts(self, response):
        print("Value finding function activted.")
        #print(response.headers, response.body)
        print(response.css("head"))
        for description in response.css("head"):
            print("level 1 value")
            value = response.css("description.content").extract()
            print(value)
```

Expected output is:

```
Parsed info
User: <a href="/profiles/76561198017108***">user</a>
Steam ID: /profiles/76561198017108***
(SOME VALUE)
```

Current output is:

```
2018-06-15 15:08:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET 
file:///Users/max/Documents/promotebot/tutorial/tutorial/TF2ITEMS.htm> (referer: None)
Parsed info
User: <a href="/profiles/76561198017108466">cakedog</a>
Steam ID: /profiles/76561198017108466
Downloading Page...
2018-06-15 15:08:12 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.backpack.tf/robots.txt> from <GET http://www.backpack.tf/robots.txt>
2018-06-15 15:08:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.backpack.tf/robots.txt> (referer: None) ['cached']
2018-06-15 15:08:12 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.backpack.tf/profiles/76561198017108466> from <GET http://www.backpack.tf/profiles/76561198017108466>
2018-06-15 15:08:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.backpack.tf/profiles/76561198017108466> (referer: None) ['cached']
Parsed info
User: <a href="/profiles/76561198015589573">Jarvis Frapner</a>
Steam ID: /profiles/76561198015589573
Page successfully downloaded.
Value finding function activted.
2018-06-15 15:08:12 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.backpack.tf/profiles/76561198017108466> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/promotebot/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/accounts_spider.py", line 38, in parse_accounts
    print(response.css("head"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/__init__.py", line 99, in css
    raise NotSupported("Response content isn't text")
NotSupported: Response content isn't text
```

Despite the multithreading(the linkgen generator downloading the request while the parse function is activating it again), the function should still work(?) I can't seem to convert the HTTP response to a text object.

Comment: Try `print response` and see what you get?

Comment: @TarunLalwani

{'Expect-Ct': ['max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"'], 'X-Powered-By': ['React/alpha'], 'Set-Cookie': ['user-id=w2t07lkjqpfan31v1xqv; Max-Age=7776000; HttpOnly; Domain=.www.backpack.tf; Path=/'], 'Date': ['Wed, 13 Jun 2018 15:16:31 GMT'], 'Cf-Ray': ['42a584caef8ca8b7-CDG']}, '\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    \n    \n<!-- have a nice day <3 -->\n<title>cakedog&#039;s TF2 Backpack - backpack.tf...

etc... It's a regular HTML page, but shouldn't parse_accounts() still work? Parse() does, and it has the same type of input